# Get placemark within polygon google earth api

Tags: api, polygon, google-earth, marker

I'm new in developing google earth application. I want to know how to get the placemark is inbound a polygon I draw. thanks in advance.

my code is

```
var ge;
var pm = null;
var isMouseDown = false;
var lineStringPlacemark = null;
var coords = null;
var pointCount = 0;
var doc = null;
var markers = [];
var polygons;

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
    google.earth.createInstance('map', initCB, failureCB);

}

function initCB(instance) {
   ge = instance;
   ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
   // add a navigation control
   ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

   //create document
   doc = ge.createDocument('');
   ge.getFeatures().appendChild(doc);

   // add some event
   google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'mousemove', onmousemove); 
   google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'mousedown', function(event) { onmousedown(event); });

   loadData(ge);
}

function failureCB(errorCode) {
    alert(errorCode);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

function loadData(ge){
   EarthRequest = new htmldb_Get(null,$v('pFlowId'),'APPLICATION_PROCESS=LoadEarthData',$v('pFlowStepId'));
   EarthData = EarthRequest.get();

   if (EarthData) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(EarthData);
        //printObject(data.row);
        $.each(data.row,function(item){
             latitude = parseFloat(data.row[item]['LATITUDE']);
             longitude = parseFloat(data.row[item]['LONGITUDE']);
             if(latitude==0 || longitude==0 || isNaN(latitude) || isNaN(longitude)){
              //do nothing
             }
             else{
                 marker = createMarker(ge,data.row[item]['CELL_ID']+' '+data.row[item]['SITE_NAME'],latitude ,longitude,data.row[item]['CELL_ID']);
                 if(marker){
            markers.push(marker);
         }
             }
        });

    var la = ge.createLookAt('');
    la.set(latitude, longitude,
      0,
      ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
      0,
      0, 
      5000 
      );
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
   }
}

function createMarker(ge,placeName,latitude,longitude,placeId){
    placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

    var icon = ge.createIcon('');
    icon.setHref('map_new.png');
    var style = ge.createStyle(''); //create a new style
    style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon); 

    var lat = parseFloat(latitude);
    var lon = parseFloat(longitude);
    var point = ge.createPoint('');
    point.setLatitude(lat);
    point.setLongitude(lon);

    placemark.setStyleSelector(style); //apply the style to the placemark
    placemark.setGeometry(point);

    // add the placemark to the earth DOM
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

    placemark.setName(placeName);

    google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'click', function(event) {
         loadPlaceDetail(placeId);
    });

    return placemark;
}

function onmousemove(event) {
  if (isMouseDown) {
   coords.pushLatLngAlt(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude(), 0);
  }
}

//convert line to polygon
function convertLineStringToPolygon(placemark) {
  var polygon = ge.createPolygon('');
  var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');
  polygon.setOuterBoundary(outer);

  var lineString = placemark.getGeometry();
  for (var i = 0; i < lineString.getCoordinates().getLength(); i++) {
    var coord = lineString.getCoordinates().get(i);
    outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(coord.getLatitude(), 
                                     coord.getLongitude(), 
                                     coord.getAltitude());
  }
  placemark.setGeometry(polygon);
  return polygon;
}

//mouse click event
function onmousedown(event) {
  if (isMouseDown) { 
        var lastdoc = doc.getFeatures().getChildNodes().getLength();

        isMouseDown = false;
        coords.pushLatLngAlt(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude(), 0);
        convertLineStringToPolygon(lineStringPlacemark);
    if(lastdoc>1){
        doc.getFeatures().removeChild(doc.getFeatures().getFirstChild());
                //I want to add some function to calculate polygon bound
        }

  } else {
    if(event.getAltKey()){

       isMouseDown = true;
       lineStringPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
       var lineString = ge.createLineString('');
       lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(lineString);
       lineString.setTessellate(true);
       lineString.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND);

       lineStringPlacemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
       var lineStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
       lineStyle.setWidth(4);
       lineStyle.getColor().set('ddffffff');  // aabbggrr formatx
       lineStyle.setColorMode(ge.COLOR_RANDOM);
       var polyStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getPolyStyle();
       polyStyle.getColor().set('ddffffff');  // aabbggrr format
       polyStyle.setColorMode(ge.COLOR_RANDOM);

       coords = lineString.getCoordinates();
       coords.pushLatLngAlt(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude(), 0);

      //doc = ge.createDocument('');
       doc.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);
    }
  }
}
```

So after  convertLineStringToPolygon run, I need to get polygon bound and reload data. if the position in bound the polygon create placemark and if no skip it. for google map can use GPolygon.Contains() method. but for google earth I didn't find yet the solution

here's the example google map from ecoynm : http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_inside.htm

Comment: Please, put some code of what you have tried. Stackoverflow [is not your research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/188968).

Answer (score 0):

[GEarthExtensions point in poly](http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/examples/point-in-poly.html)

use the google earth extention library http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/

the example is uses the mouse move event

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'mousemove', function(evt) {
  var poly = new geo.Polygon(pts);
  var contains = poly.containsPoint(
      new geo.Point(evt.getLatitude(), evt.getLongitude()));
  placemark.setStyleSelector(contains ? onStyle : offStyle);
});
```